# Compiling a dll from a vb.net assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, custom-server-controls

I'm attempting to make a very basic server control in VB.Net and am working my way through my own version of this [bloody awful walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f%28v=VS.90%29.aspx#Y4500).

I have got up to this bit (just over halfway down the page)...

> To compile the control into an assembly and embed the icon
>
> 1) Open the Visual Studio Command Prompt window. For more information,
>   see Command-line Building With csc.exe.
>
> 2) At the command line, switch to the directory that contains the custom
>   control class files.

How do I 'switch to directory' in the Command Prompt window?

Any other prescient advice on problems I may encounter would be more than welcome also! :D

**UPDATE**

I'm now in Visual Studio Command Prompt standalone app and have had this discourse...

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>vbc "D:\data\oconndr\ASP Custom
Controls\CustomControls\CustomTreeView.vb"  /t:library /out:CustomTree.dll /r:Sy
stem.dll /r:System.Web.dll
Microsoft (R) Visual Basic Compiler version 9.0.30729.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>
```

As you can see it gives me no indication that it's built a dll (probably becuase it hasn't).

How do I compile `CustomTreeView.vb` to a dll??

**UPDATE**

For any poor unfortunates in a similar position I ended up doing...

```
vbc /target:library /out:"D:\data\oconndr\ASP Custom Controls\CustomControls\CustomTree.dll" "D:\data\oconndr\ASP Custom Controls\CustomControls\CustomTreeView.vb"
```

ie

```
vbc /target:library /out:"<Target dll Path>" "<vb file path>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using the Visual Studio Command Prompt (an application similar to cmd, which can be found in your VS installation directory), not the integrated Command Window in VS.

Usually it is located here: `[Your Visual Studio Dir]\VC\vcvarsall.bat`

Then try the DOS command to change the directory: `cd`

Solve the issue with the spaces in the path by surrounding it with quotation marks like this:

```
vbc "D:\data\custom controls\CustomTree\CustomTree.vb" /out:...
```

For further reference, here's the [MSDN documentation on how to invoke the command-line compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/380cz5k4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Make sure, you're using the right tool. See my edited post above.

Comment: Thanks for your update - I've opened Microsoft Visual Studio Command Prompt from the Start menu - which looks more like cmd. I've managed to use `cd` to change directory. I'm trying to run this command : `vbc D:\data\custom controls\CustomTree\CustomTree.vb /out:CustomTree.dll /r:System.dll /r:System.Web.dll` It then can't find the file because of spaces in the path...

Comment: `cd` doesn't actually look to have changed directory - but it hasn't thrown an error - the prompt is still showing the original path before the `>`...

Comment: Can't help you with the cd-issue. It's supposed to work just fine if used correctly. I updated my answer addressing the spaces in the path. Oh, and since my answer solved your original issue, please don't hesitate to accept it.